# Replace numbers in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this string: £0,00

Which i want to replace with float 3.95 for instance. But i want to keep the £ and the ","

So result -> £3,95

How would i do it?

--

Added some details:

Will the currency symbol always be a £?
The currency symbol might be before and sometimes behind the numbers. ie 0,00 kr

Will the separator always be ,, or might it be . or even an arbitrary character?
The separator might be . sometimes.

Will there always be two decimal places?
The decimal will always be 2 places.

How many integer digits might there be, and will there be a thousands separator?
It will not be above 100.

Comment: You should give more detail on the bounds of your problem.  Will the currency symbol always be a `£`?  Will the separator always be `,`, or might it be `.` or even an arbitrary character?  Will there always be two decimal places?  How many integer digits might there be, and will there be a thousands separator?  These are all important, since your original question can be answered trivially by ignoring the first and third characters, parsing the float and then adding them back in again.  The range of valid input values is the essence of the question.

Comment: Ok, good point. Will add more details

Comment: How are you storing the number you wish to replace? is it var replace = 3.95 ? or?

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/149055/how-can-i-format-numbers-as-money-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function convert (proto, value) {
  return proto.replace (/0(.)00/, function (m, dp) {
    return value.toFixed (2).replace ('.', dp);
  });
}
```

the proto parameter specifies the format, it must have a sub-string consisting of a single 0 digit followed by any character followed by two 0 digits, this entire sub-string is replaced by the numeric value parameter replacing the decimal point with the character between the 0 digits in the proto.

Comment: Nice. Changed the reg exp to read any number since the string: £0,00 can be any sum, forgot to tell that. Thanks mate!

Comment: I thought to do so but respected your specifications.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function Convert(Value) {
    return '£' + Value.toString().replace('.', ',');
}
alert(Convert(3.95));
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry, this solution doesn't take suffix ie "23.00kr" in account

Answer (score 0):

Regular expression `/(\D*)\s?([\d|.|,]+)\s?(\D*)/` will return an array with following values:

- [0] = whole string (eg "£4.30"
- [1] = prefix (eg. "£")
- [2] = numerical value (eg. "4.30")
- [3] = suffix (eg. "kr")

Usage: `var parts = /(\D*)\s?([\d|.|,]+)\s?(\D*)/.exec(myValue);`

It also handles cases where either prefix or suffix has following or leading space.

And whenever you need to replace the comma from number, just use the *value.replace(",",".")* method.